# Print a array of size n*n, with borders as 1's and fill rest of element with 0's

Tags: python, numpy

**Assessment Question:** Print an array of size n*n, with border as 1's and rest of the element as 0's.

**Sample Input:** 5

**Sample Output:**

```
[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Here is my solution:

```
import numpy as np
n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
np_box = np.zeros([n, n], dtype='int')
np_box[:, 0] = np_box[:, -1] = np_box[0] = np_box[-1] = 1
print(np_box)
```

Can this code be still optimised (using numpy, considering space and time complexity)?

Comment: Because printing is involved, the problem cannot be large scale. And you've delegated the work to numpy. In light of those things, why is memory/speed optimization an issue here at all?

Answer (score 1):

Have you alread checked out np.pad?

```
import numpy as np
n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
np_box = np.pad(np.zeros((n-1,n-1)), 1, constant_values=1)
```